# How to cache parallelly computed results with memoise::memoise?

Tags: r, memoise

I am precomputing results and caching them with the `memoise` function of the [memoise](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memoise/README.html) package.  Unfortunately, if I try to speed up the calculations by running them in parallel with `parallel::mclapply`, the memoisation does not happen.

```
> f <- memoise::memoise(function (a, b) a)
> memoise::has_cache(f)("foo", "bar")
[1] FALSE

> parallel::mclapply(c("bar", "baz"), f, a = "foo")
[[1]]
[1] "foo"

[[2]]
[1] "foo"

> memoise::has_cache(f)("foo", "bar")
[1] FALSE

> sapply(c("bar", "baz"), f, a = "foo")
  bar   baz 
"foo" "foo" 
> memoise::has_cache(f)("foo", "bar")
[1] TRUE
```

I suppose that the memoised function is copied and then discarded in each fork...  Is there a simple alternative using other functions or packages ?

Comment: The R.cache package (I'm the author) memoizes to file, which means the cache works across R sessions and in parallel R processes. Obviously, caching to file adds a bit of overhead compared to caching to memory.

Comment: Indeed, `R.cache::addMemoization()` fits exactly my needs, thank you very much. Can you change your comment into an answer so that I can mark it accepted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer:*

The [R.cache](https://cran.r-project.org/package=R.cache) package (I'm the author) memoizes to file, which means the cache works across R sessions and in parallel R processes. Obviously, caching to file adds a bit of overhead compared to caching to memory.